# How to post data to firebase once user is already logged in

Tags: xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to firebase and I'm making an app with an integrated quiz feature using Xcode, but I can't figure how to post the score of the quiz to firebase. This is what I have so far:

```
@IBAction func saveScore(_ sender: Any) {

    let scores = self.lblScore.text!

    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let dict = ["score": scores]
    db.collection("users").addDocument(data: dict)
}
```

This posts the score to firebase, however it posts in a separate document. I want it to be posted to the document of the user that is logged in. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `addDocument`, Firestore generates a new document with its own unique ID. So the behavior you're seeing is expected for the code you have.

If you want to have a single, specific document for each user, you'll typically use the UID of the user as the ID for their document. A simple way to do that, is:

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
if let user = user {
    db.collection("users").document(user.uid).setData(data: dict)
}
```

Also see the Firestore documentation on [adding data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) and the documentation on [determining the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).